# Is it possible to pass object variable to "use" section in anonymous function

Tags: php, laravel, oop, laravel-5, php-7

So basically I am trying to pass current object variable to my anonymous function like this:

```php
$options = Option::whereHas('texts', function($query) use ($this->language) {
        $query->where(['language_id' => $this->language->id, ]);
    })->where(['active' => 1, ])
    ->get();
```

But it gives:

> syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ')'`.

Anyway, if I will set another variable to `$this->language` and pass it in anonymous function, it will work properly.

```php
$language = $this->language;
$options = Option::whereHas('texts', function($query) use ($language) {
        $query->where(['language_id' => $language->id, ]);
    })->where(['active' => 1, ])
    ->get();
```

So, what is correct way to pass object variable to "use" section in anonymous function?

Comment: The second one: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> As of PHP 5.4.0, when declared in the context of a class, the current class is automatically bound to it, making *$this* available inside of the function's scope. If this automatic binding of the current class is not wanted, then [static anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous-functions.static) may be used instead.

Since you're using a non-static anonymous function inside of a class, the `$this` variable is automatically bound to the function without needing to `use` it. This should work fine to access the language inside your function.

```
$options = Option::whereHas('texts', function($query) {
    $query->where(['language_id' => $this->language->id]);
})
->where(['active' => 1])
->get();
```

If, however, you didn't want to do that, and you wanted to `use` a variable, you should think of the `use` statement as a second set of defined arguments. For example, you can't defined a function like `function test($this) {}` or `function test($obj->property) {}`, so you can't have that format in your `use` statement.

You need to assign whatever you want to make available to your anonymous function to a variable, and then `use` that variable.